# retrieve the data from json folder with angularjs

Tags: javascript, html, json, angularjs

Hello I try to make a angularjs application so i retrieve a data from a json folder but it's display lik this ["adventure","sci-fi"]
how can I please remove [" "] from this ["adventure","sci-fi"]

this is my json folder

```
[
    {
      "title": "Interstellar",
      "genre": [
        "adventure",
        "sci-fi"
      ],
      "watched": false
    },
    {
      "title": "Inception",
      "genre": [
        "action",
        "mystery",
        "sci-fi"
      ],
      "watched": true
    }
]
```

and this my service.js

```
var app = angular.module('appMovies', [] );


app.service('moviesService', function($http,$q){

    var deferred =$q.defer();
    $http.get('movies.json').then(function (data)
    {
        deferred.resolve(data);

        });

    this.getPlayers = function ()
    {
        return deferred.promise;
    }
})
```

and this my controller

```
app.controller('appcontrolles', function($scope,moviesService){
    var promise = moviesService.getPlayers();
    promise.then(function(data)
{
    $scope.players =data.data;
    console.log($scope.players);
});
})
```

and this is my index.html

```
    <table class="table table-striped">
        <thead>

            <tr>

                <th>title</th>
                <th>genre</th>
                <th>watched</th>
            </tr>

        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr ng-repeat="movie in players | filter : genre |filter: search.genre |filter : watched ">

                <td>{{movie.title}}</td>
                <td>{{movie.genre}}</td>
                <td><input type="checkbox" name="vu", ng-model="movie.watched",value="true"></td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

Since `movie.genre` is an array, when you just put `{{movie.genre}}`, Angular outputs the value as a string representing an array: `["adventure","sci-fi"]`.

If you want a simple comma-delimited list of values, you could use the `.join()` function of an array to create a string with a specify delimiter, like `", "`, like so:

```
<td>{{movie.genre.join(", ")}}</td>
```

Alternatively, if you want more complex DOM around it, then you could `ng-repeat` over that array:

```
<td><span ng-repeat="genre in movie.genre">{{genre}}</span></td>
```

**Off Topic:**

You don't need to use `$q.defer` with something that already returns a promise, like `$http` - you can just return that promise, and so your service could be simplified to:

```
app.service('moviesService', function($http){
    this.getPlayers = function()
    {
        return $http.get('movies.json');
    }
});
```

`$q.defer` is used when you are trying to convert a non-promise async function of some third-party service, for example, which uses `on-success` and `on-error` handlers.